# Как добавить строку в определенный столбец ttk.Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Не могу разобраться никак...

Есть программа, которая открывает таблицу excel, и есть таблица от tkinter.ttk. Как мне добавить строки в определенный столбец, а не в один?

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('1', '2', '3'), height=10, show='headings')
self.tree.column('1', width=setting, anchor=to.CENTER)
self.tree.column('2', width=setting, anchor=to.CENTER)
self.tree.column('3', width=setting, anchor=to.CENTER)

self.tree.heading('1', text='#1')
self.tree.heading('2', text='#2')
self.tree.heading('3', text='#3')

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for j in range(3):
    for i in range(5):
        self.tree.insert(' ', 'end', values=(sh.row_values(j)[i])
```

Как сделать, чтобы значения из таблицы xlsx добавлялись в 1, 2 и 3юю колонку таблицы Treeview?

Comment: Попробуйте в values вставлять сразу строку целиком, без цикла по i: `self.tree.insert(' ', 'end', values=sh.row_values(j))`

Comment: @insolor помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь вы вставляете по одной ячейке в отдельные строки:

```
for j in range(3):
    for i in range(5):
        self.tree.insert(' ', 'end', values=(sh.row_values(j)[i])
```

Нужно вставлять строку целиком, как-то так:

```
for j in range(3):
    self.tree.insert(' ', 'end', values=sh.row_values(j))
```